# Weird text in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I just installed android studio in my windows. But here is what I get:

[image: Android Studio Wizard Screen]

How to fix my android studio?

Comment: Looks like encoding issue. Check your language preferences. What is your system locale and language? Which language of android studio setup you've downloaded? Read [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: @JustasŠpakauskas I think that is not my issue. Sorry

Comment: Btw after restart my computer, my A.S get normal. Solved

Answer (score 3):

This solved to me:
([Unrecognized characters in the Android Studio Setup Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775813/unrecognized-characters-in-the-android-studio-setup-wizard)).
Just removed Bizagi Studio and everything work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have choosen a different language set package to download (or it was the option you took at install time - if this feature is available). The weird characters are displayed probably because your system seems not to know how to handle this different language set (can be chinese, japanese, arabic, cirilic etc). Try installing A.S. again, to see if you have language options, or try downloading the correct A.S. for your language.

Comment: I think that is not my issue. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Change the windows fonts using WinAeroTweaker. working 100%