# Unrecognized characters in the Android Studio Setup Wizard

Tags: android-studio

I'm having a strange behavior when trying to install Android Studio on a Windows machine.
During the installation screen appear unknown characters. 
I removed and installed again several times and the same problem occurs.

Has anyone identified this situation?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps change your Windows system default font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the Bizagi Studio and Visual Code.

After removing these programs, the setup worked.