# Android Studio weird installation language

Tags: android, android-studio

Weird Language

[image]

Hello guys, as you can see the image, My Android Studio looking weird. I dont understand the language. How to fix this issue?

There is similar question about it, [Weird Text Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533679/weird-text-in-android-studio), but it doesnt fix my problem. I dont have any program like visual code or bizagi studio

Comment: Well, what if you install it by usual way (next - next - finish)?

Comment: i install in usual way... next - next - finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to `C:\Users\{username}\AndroidStudio\config\options`
2. Open `ui.inf.xml` file in editor like Notepad or Notepad++
3. Add this line of code if it doesn't exist:

[image: Android Studio Language]

4. Save the changes and restart Android Studio

Comment: Im sorry but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: this solution works after I add several lines of code 
<option name="HIDE_TOOL_STRIPES" value="false" />
<option name="SHOW_MAIN_TOOLBAR" value="true" />
<option name="OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS" value="true"

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\Users{username}\AndroidStudio\config\options
2. Open ui.inf.xml file in any editor
3. Add these line of code if it doesn't exist:

```html
<option name="FONT_FACE" value="Consolas" /> 
<option name="HIDE_TOOL_STRIPES" value="false" /> 
<option name="SHOW_MAIN_TOOLBAR" value="true" /> 
<option name="OVERRIDE_NONIDEA_LAF_FONTS" value="true"/>
```

4. Save and restart Android Studio IDE