# Why my Android Studio language becomes weird?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Excuse me, I want to ask something. Maybe someone knows about this problem.
Since two months ago, my Android Studio becomes weird. I don't know what happenned to it.
I didn't change anything. I didn't do something. I just open my Android Studio like as usual and... I got this.

I already uninstall it and reinstall it. But, nothing changes. Then, I download the latest version, the 201.7042882 from its official page, https://developer.android.com/studio/.

After that, I install this latest version and nothing happenned.

Would you like to share about your experience?

[The older version (193.66xxxx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcCWP.png)

[The older version (193.66xxxx) - again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZYvy.png)

[The latest version (201.7042882)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv5Ht.png)

Comment: Uninstalling Android Studio doesn't clear older caches... you will need to clear it manually... Try Clearing all files related to Android Studio after uninstalling and try reinstalling again... This may help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Android Studio font issues in IDE menu and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523138/how-to-fix-android-studio-font-issues-in-ide-menu-and-labels)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533679/weird-text-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have changed the IDE font. go to setting by control+alt+s ,in the left tab -->(first expandable button , first button) , then in right tab --> Uncheck the second checkbox (Override Default fonts)

Comment: Thank you. It triggers me to check the 'Use Custom Font' on the setting by control+alt+s ,in the left tab -->(first expandable button , first button) , then in right tab --> check the most top checkable settings (it's 'Use Custom Font')